# Geoserver create generic dynamic style

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, style, sld, dynamic

I'm quite new to GeoServer, and I wonder if it is possible to create a dynamic style.
I got a big shapefile with more than 600 variables, and I want to create a generic style where you can input the **variable name** you want from wsm ( with leaflet for example ).

I saw that geoserver got something called **[Variable substitution in SLD](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/substitution.html)** but I'm not sure if you can achieve it with this?

Comment: what sort of variables do you have? it may not make any sense to display all 600 with the same style.

Comment: Sorry if I explained wrong. I got 600 variables, but I ony want to display them 1 by 1 depending on the request.
For example I got male population  and female population, and I want to send in the request wich variable to use